# css selector not last child not working (pure css solution needed)

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Not sure why the following css selector won't work. Want to enter 100 in all fields except last one in DOM. Would prefer a pure css solution, i.e. not add .not(":last") in jQuery.

```js
$("input[id^=FIELD]:not(:last-child)").val("100");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="FIELD1" value="2">
<input id="FIELD2" value="2">
<input id="FIELD3" value="2">
<input id="FIELD4" value="2">
```

Comment: Why do you need a pure CSS solution when you're working with jQuery?

Comment: I think he meant a solution using a purely CSS-based selector.

Comment: Does the selector need to be a valid CSS selector, or can it use any of the non-standard jQuery ones?

Comment: You've picked the wrong answer.

Comment: Yes see :last is a jQuery addon I see now.

Comment: You've picked the wrong answer a second time... The answer you picked provides an alternate solution, but fails to address the source of your problem - because your code is *just fine*.

Comment: All answer are wrong except you? @connexo explain why my answer is wrong?

Comment: I explained it in my comment. OP's code would work just fine in the real world, it's just SO snippets break OP's code.

Comment: @connexo Also for sure OP code not working in localhost or anywhere else, out of stackoverflow. So what? When my solution work  why you say it's wrong? if you want more rep, okay no problem, say it first.

Comment: OP's code will work in the real world: http://codestylers.de/last-child.html

Comment: @Pedram Have you checked?

Comment: It's ridiculous, you mean OP create snippet first then found out it not working then post this question? OP came here ask about the problem, before create any snippet. after all this, it doesn't matter for me, I just saying my answer not wrong, you right I didn't mention why it not working here (on SO) but it's really a solution, end of the story. Accepting an answer is up to OP opinion and choice not mine. Your answer is right too but when OP can solve the problem with a quick and simple and short way, why should use another? by the way... @connexo

Comment: *Also for sure OP code not working in localhost or anywhere else, out of stackoverflow.* That was **your claim** and I have just **proven you wrong**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`:last-child` won't work because it need a `parent` so use `:last-of-type`

```js
$('input[id^=FIELD]:not(:last-of-type)').val("100");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="FIELD1" value="2">
<input id="FIELD2" value="2">
<input id="FIELD3" value="2">
<input id="FIELD4" value="2">
```

With parent:

```js
$('#mydiv input[id^=FIELD]:not(:last-child)').val("100");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
  <input id="FIELD1" value="2">
  <input id="FIELD2" value="2">
  <input id="FIELD3" value="2">
  <input id="FIELD4" value="2">
</div>
```

Comment: As I already commented under connexo's answer, "the parent in the question is body" so there's no reason :last-child should fail to work with the markup given. The underlying cause is explained elsewhere.

Comment: @BoltClock You are welcome to down vote, what ever... my answer not wrong, I said this a thousand times.. no reason to any down vote or etc.. OP want to accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

### StackOverflow snippet breaks your code.

Your code is fine, but it needs an explicit `parent` element for `:last-child` to work in a StackOverflow snippet.

Usually without explicitly adding `body` on StackOverflow that would be the `body` element that gets inserted automatically, but for some strange reason related to how StackOverflow snippets work you explicitly need to add a parent element on SO for the selector to work as expected.

### Edit

I just checked with CodePen and JSBin, both seem to create the same problem:

> http://jsbin.com/ceguvogoza/1/edit?html,js,output
>
> https://codepen.io/connexo/pen/KQYjKR

#### Proof your code works in a real world environment:

> http://codestylers.de/last-child.html

```js
function usingVanillaJs() {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[id^='FIELD']:not(:last-child)")).forEach((input) => {
    input.value = 100;
  })
}

function usingJquery() {
  $("input[id^='FIELD']:not(:last-child)").val(200);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="FIELD1" value="2">
  <input id="FIELD2" value="2">
  <input id="FIELD3" value="2">
  <input id="FIELD4" value="2">
</div>
<button onclick="usingVanillaJs()">Vanilla JS</button>
<button onclick="usingJquery()">jQuery</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, the parent in the question is body, and yet :last-child still doesn't work. The reason for that is explained somewhere on meta. I have no idea if it's covered anywhere on the main site - if it is, then this is yet another duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("input[id^=FIELD]").not(":last").val("100");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="FIELD1" value="2">
<input id="FIELD2" value="2">
<input id="FIELD3" value="2">
<input id="FIELD4" value="2">
```

for CSS selector, Just change `last-child` to `last`:

```
$("input[id^=FIELD]:not(:last)").val("100");
```

If you add a parent to your selector the `last-child` will work too:

```
 $("#parentDiv input[id^=FIELD]:not(:last-child)").val("100");
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to write I would prefer a pure css solution, otherwise perfect suggestion :)

Comment: Ok. I have updated the answer with both css and jquery selector

Comment: OP asked for a purely CSS-based selector. `:last` **is** CSS, but it is for printing, selecting `page`. jQuery just created their own `:first` and `:last` deviating from the specifications, which means that this will e.g. not work using Vanilla JS.

Comment: Which means jQuery's `:last` has nothing to do with CSS's `:last`.

Comment: Also this fails to point out what the actual problem was with OP's approach. Bad answer.

Comment: I have updated the answer again by adding third method using css selector. @connexo

Comment: Still you don't explain why OP's approach didn't work - which it should and would if it was not for SO's snippet functionality breaking it.